# How do I disable all Source Mapping in Safari DevTools?

Tags: safari, development

In a minified jQuery file I'm using, this snippet at the end: `//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map` is causing an annoying 404 error to appear in the Developer Console on every refresh.

I don't have the `.min.map` file and don't intend to get it.

Is there a way I can make Safari DevTools to ignore these annotations and never complain about missing Source Maps? I rarely need that feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no 'disable source map' option in safari.

I'm also not interested in these red lines in my console log. And tackled the problem from the other end, by letting the server give empty 200 responses for .map files

For nginx it's done by adding the next line to your config

```
location ~ \.map$ {return 200;}
```

I know this is dirty, but hey it works...